# Boot problems following update of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on 32 bit PC

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates, 32-bit

About a month ago I installed ubuntu 16 LTS on my 32 bit Lenovo laptop via the 32 bit ISO. That went fine. Since I wanted ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I followed that with a network install of 18.04 LTS. That went fine too.

Then last week the System Update window popped up and said it had about 180 MB worth of update to install (which included a new kernel). So I went ahead and installed that. The install appeared to go fine, but after the restart following the upgrade, all I got was a purple screen with a band of random color pixels across the top. Never got to a login screen. Fn-Alt-Ctrl-F3, F4, etc. would not get me to a console login screen.

Now if I hold down the power button to power the lap top off and push it again to start it up, it automatically boots into GRUB and if I let GRUB time out, it boots the "Ubuntu" selection at the top of the list of selections and the system boots up fine. It takes a while, but I get a GUI login window and I can use the system just fine.

Fine, that is, until I power it off, at which point on the next power up I get the purple screen with the random colored pixels again with no login screen. I then have to power cycle the laptop with its on/off button again to get back to GRUB at which point it boots fine again.

Various web references make mention of an "Ubuntu Boot Repair" procedure that involves creating an Ubuntu Live CD, booting the laptop off that Live CD, adding a PPA repository, installing boot-repair and then running boot-repair, ex this one:

https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-boot-repair

However, instructions say that I need an Live CD to do this and apparently no Ubuntu 18.04 Live CD ISOs are available for 32 bit PCs.

It occurs to me that since I can get the laptop to boot following its pass through the GRUB menu, then I can at least attempt to add the PPA repository and then install and run boot-repair. But what's not clear to me is whether or not that would be a safe procedure since at that point I would not be running the system off the Live CD but off the installed image.

My questions are:

1. Should I install boot-repair as described and run it even though I would not at that point be running off the Live CD?
2. Are there any other avenues I should try to get my laptop to boot correctly from power up without having to go through GRUB?

===================== a little later =====================

I went ahead and installed boot-repair and ran it. It said it successfully repaired grub but on the following reboot, the problem persisted.

GRUB presents me with these choices if I hold the SHIFT key down during boot and select advanced boot options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-48-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-47-generic (recovery mode)
```

If I select "Linux 4.15.0-48-generic", the problem described above occurs (or some variant of it, a lot of display weirdness, flashing screens, random colored pixels, the behavior is not consistent across boots). If I select "Linux 4.15.0-47-generic", it boots up to a working desktop every time.

So I think 4.15.0-48-generic has a video driver bug that manifests on my Lenovo and that bug is new to that version since 4.15.0-47 its predecessor works fine.

Comment: Boot Repair is NOT for this cases.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did you install a video driver? And if so how? If you install directly from nVidia, it only installs to that one kernel & you have to reinstall it to new kernels. If you install video driver from Ubuntu repository, then it automatically updates a new kernel to include it.

Answer (score 0):

> What brand/model system?

Lenovo G500 laptop, 32 bit. Its about 5 years old.

> What video card/chip?

Gee, I don't know. Whatever video hardware that came with the laptop.

> Did you install a video driver?

No.

This problem has been reported by others at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1827884